# Inserting in object of type bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have an object of type bytes in python:

```
a = b'\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00'
```

How can I insert `\x89PNG\`such that the resulting bytes become:

```
b = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Other than the obvious `b  = b'\x89PNG' + a`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: @chepner would you like to post your comment as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `bytes` objects are immutable, you simply need to create a new object using concatenation:

```
b = b'\x89PNG' + a
```